# Pulling Cuisine Type from TripAdvisor Restaurants using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to pull data from TripAdvisor Restaurant from different countries. The fields I am trying to pull is name, address, and cuisine type (chinese, steakhouse, etc.). I have successfully been able to pull name and address using my script; however, pulling cuisine type is proving pretty difficult for myself. If you take a look below, you'll find screenshots of what I am trying to pull from TripAdvisor, and my code.

[What I want to pull from TripAdvisor is circled in red.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajaFg.png)

[When I print my code it keeps printing 'Asian' even thought the second one should be a 'Steakhouse'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsGks.png)

```
#import libraries
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

#loop to move into the next pages. entries are in increments of 30 per page
for i in range(0, 120, 30):
    #need this here for when you want more than 30 entries pulled
    while i <= range:
        i = str(i)
        #url format offsets the restaurants in increments of 30 after the oa
        url1 = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurants-g294217-oa' + i + '-Hong_Kong.html#EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS'
        r1 = requests.get(url1)
        data1 = r1.text
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(data1, "html.parser")
        for link in soup1.findAll('a', {'property_title'}):
            #print 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294217-' + link.get('href')
            restaurant_url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g294217-' + link.get('href')
            #print link.string
            account_name = link.string.strip()
            #cuisine type pull
            for link in soup1.findAll('a', {'cuisine'}):
                cuisinetype = link.string.strip()
            r_address = requests.get(restaurant_url)
            r_addresstext = r_address.text
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r_addresstext, "html.parser")
            for restaurant_url in soup2.findAll('span', {'street-address'})[0]:
                #print(restaurant_url.string)
                rest_address = restaurant_url.string
                rest_array = [account_name, rest_address, cuisinetype]
                print rest_array
                #with open('ListingsPull-HongKong.csv', 'a') as file:
                    #writer = csv.writer(file)
                    #writer.writerow([account_name, rest_address])
        break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach is not especially elegant but might be acceptable to you. I notice that the information you want seems to be repeated under the 'Details' tab for 'Cuisine'. I've found it easier to access there this way.

```
>>> import requests
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> restaurant_url='https://www.tripadvisor.ca/Restaurant_Review-g294217-d2399904-Reviews-Tin_Lung_Heen-Hong_Kong.html'
>>> soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(restaurant_url).text, "html.parser")
>>> street_address=soup2.find('span',{'street-address'})
>>> street_address
<span class="street-address" property="streetAddress">International Commerce Centre, 1 Austin Road West, Kowloon</span>
>>> street_address.contents[0]
'International Commerce Centre, 1 Austin Road West, Kowloon'
>>> for item in soup2.findAll('div', attrs={'class', 'title'}):
...     if 'Cuisine' in item.text:
... 
...         item.text.strip()
...         break
...         
'Cuisine'
>>> content=item.findNext('div', attrs={'class', 'content'})
>>> content
<div class="content">
Chinese, Asian
</div>
>>> content.text
'\nChinese,\xa0Asian\n'
>>> content.text.strip().split('\xa0')
['Chinese,', 'Asian']
```

Comment: Your solution is working for the most part but I am having a hard time splitting the '\xa0' because pycharm doesn't recognize the string when I add the backslash. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Oh. I imagine you need an 'r' ahead of it, like this:

r'\xa0'

Comment: Got the program to recognize the string. But I still can't get it to perform the split function correctly. It's still printing out the entire line of HTML.

Comment: Can you display the content.text that you want to split here?

Comment: The array prints out this now:

Comment: >[u'Braza Churrascaria Brazilian Steakhouse', u'3/F, Grand Progress Building, No.15-16 Lan Kwai Fong, Central', <div class="content">\nSteakhouse,\xa0Brazilian,\xa0Barbecue,\xa0South American\n</div>]

Comment: Take the last item in that list, I will call it **content**, and get its **text**:

>>> content.text
'\nSteakhouse,\xa0Brazilian,\xa0Barbecue,\xa0South American\n'

It has non-ascii unicode characters in it which you can delete using:

>>> content.text.encode('ascii','ignore')
b'\nSteakhouse,Brazilian,Barbecue,South American\n'

But now I can't demonstrate anything more because I'm using Python 3. You should get a string from this where I've got a byte array (that's the 'b' at the beginning). You should be able to strip the '\n' characters, then split on the commas. I hope it works!

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much! I am very new to this. Definitely going to put this in my bag of tricks! Thank you!

Comment: You are very, very welcome! Glad I could make a difference.